# How I can launch Sublime Text 2 from the Mac OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext2

I have tried to launch Sublime Text 2 from Terminal, and I have followed the instruction on Github from this link https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170#installation ,but I`m steel have problem. I`m trying to make ~bin/ directory in Terminal $ mkdir -p /usr/local/bin   ,but I`m getting this error : mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Permission denied. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`sudo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) command, which essentially means you are running the command as user `root`. Be very careful when using `sudo`, as you can really mess up your system if you type something incorrectly.

To use it, make sure you have Administrator privileges. Then, run

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
```

to make `/usr/local/bin`, if it doesn't exist already. Then, run

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

to create a `sublime` symlink in `/usr/local/bin`. Finally, edit your `~/.profile` file to add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH, save it, restart Terminal, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```